# descargar imagenes de AzureStorage File

Tags: azure-storage

Estoy creando una **DLL** que me permita conectarme a `AzureStorage`.

la idea es que la **DLL** me permita subir imágenes a una ruta específica y también me permita descargas las imágenes  y obtenerlas en un Arreglo.

La **DLL** debe usar los métodos de `azureStorage`. en el momento ya cree el método para subir las imágenes que es el siguiente:

```
  public string Save(string connectionkeys, string path, string fileName, Stream content)
        {
            string imageUrl = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                CloudFileDirectory directory = settings.GetDirectory(path);
                CloudFile cloudFile = directory.GetFileReference(fileName);
                cloudFile.UploadFromStreamAsync(content);
                imageUrl = Convert.ToString(cloudFile.StorageUri.PrimaryUri);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }

            return imageUrl;
        }
```

en este método estoy usando las librerías de `azure`.

estoy necesitando el método para descargas esas imágenes y guardarlas en un `array`.

si alguien me puede ayudar se los agradezco mucho

Comment: Hola, aca te explican el paso a paso para descargar desde azure storage https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip76.html#download-a-file

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza la librería **`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob`**

ejemplo:

```
 try
   {
     // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
     CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

     // Create the blob client.
     CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

     // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
     CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(nameContainer);

     // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
     CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(nameFile);

     // Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.

     using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
     {
         blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
     }
    }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {

 }
```

Revisa este enlace: (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet)